Is there a bug in tkz-euclide with the R option (as radius)?
Both macros \tkzDrawCircle[R] and \tkzInterLC[R] give this error when using the R option which should allow to draw a circle knowing its radius.
And this is regardless of how the points P, d and e are defined with \tkzDefPoint or \tkzDefPoints

Package pgf Error: No shape named `5' is known. See the pgf package
documentation for explanation. Type H  for immediate help. ...
l.22 \tkzDrawCircleR

What is the problem?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(5,-3.5){P}
\tkzDefPoint{2,0){d}
\tkzDefPoint(10,0){e}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](P,5)
\tkzInterLC[R](d,e)(P,5) 
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{5/-3.5/P, 2/0/d, 10/0/e}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](P,5)
\tkzInterLC[R](d,e)(P,5) 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


No it’s not a bug. Option « R » is used only with \tkzDefCircle.
To be more precise, with version 5, to draw a circle it is necessary to give two points: the centre and a point on the circle, so the R option is hardly compatible with this method.
After \tkzDefCircle you need to get the point on the circle
\tkzDefCircle[R](C,5) \tkzGetPoint{B}
\tkzDrawCircle(C,B)


But, on page 130, the manual say \tkzDrawCircle[⟨local options⟩](⟨A,B⟩) Attention you need only two points to define a radius. An additional option R is available to give a measure directly

@AndréC This is an inaccuracy in the documentation that should have been changed with version 5.
